# Query Community Reputation Level Image

Tags: lightning, community, reputation

Is there any possible way to query Reputation Level(Community) image in Apex. We understood that it is possible via connectedApi, but instead of connectedApi, Is it possible to get it directly by querying an object in salesforce.[image]

Comment: Dang it, I'd have to stay at 50 points :(

Comment: @sfdcfox : Is possible to query it? I am searching lot of blogs and i didn't get any answer though. Basically we need to understand is it safe to use connectedApi in public lightning community?. We really don't want get into connectedAPI limitation for guest users. :(